Connectivity of Unit Map between Thom Spaces
Let $\gamma_n^\perp \to \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the orthogonal complement bundle over the Grassmannian of oriented $2$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. in particular it is an $(n-2)$-dimensional vector bundle. I am trying to show the following claim about Thom spaces:

The unit of the loopspace-suspension adjunction $\eta : \text{Th}(\gamma_n^\perp) \to \Omega\Sigma \text{Th}(\gamma_n^\perp)$ is (at least) $(2n-4)$-connected.

I am able to show that $\text{Th}(\gamma_n^\perp)$ is an $(n-3)$-connected space. The Freudenthal Suspension Theorem then shows that the map $\eta : \text{Th}(\gamma_n^\perp) \to \Omega\Sigma \text{Th}(\gamma_n^\perp)$ is $(2\cdot(n-3)+1 = 2n-5)$-connected, which is almost what I want, but not quite. Unfortunately, I can't improve the result purely with Freudenthal, since one can show that $\pi_{n-2}(\text{Th}(\gamma_n^\perp)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, i.e. the space $\text{Th}(\gamma_n^\perp)$ is not $(n-2)$-connected. Now I'm unsure how to continue or what other approaches I could possibly use.
Any hints/suggestions on how to improve my work are welcome, thanks!

This should be equivalent by the EHP sequence to the smash product $Th(\gamma_n^{\perp})\land Th(\gamma_n^{\perp})$ being $(2n-4)$-connected. I don't know why that would be true, though.

Excellent question! Was just wondering the same thing...

@Thorgott Thanks for the hint, I found the relevant sequence in Hatcher's textbook now. Maybe I can figure something out from here!
